# Recarregar página com MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Fiz uma função na model e a chamada na controller. Aí, passo para o jquery e o comando de gravar no BD é excutado com êxito. Acontece, que quando eu termino de gravar, a tela continua com as informações anteriores, ou seja, os textbox preenchidos, os checkbox's checados. Como eu faço para após a gravação no BD(sucesso do ajax) eu recarregar a página ou os campos alterados somente? Abaixo minha chamada jquery. O alerta com a mensagem pode ser desconsiderado, se necessário.

```
var checkedItemsUn = {}, checkedItemsMot = {}, checkedItemsPdv = {}, counter = 0;

function Gravar() {

    $("#check-list-box li.active").each(function (idx, li) {
        checkedItemsUn[counter] = $(li).text();
        counter++;
    });

    counter = 0

    $("#check-list-box-mot li.active").each(function (idx, li) {
        checkedItemsMot[counter] = $(li).text();
        counter++;
    });

    counter = 0

    $("#check-list-tipo li.active").each(function (idx, li) {
        checkedItemsPdv[counter] = $(li).text();
        counter++;
    });

    counter = 0
    str = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: '/CadastroCargo/GravaResponsavel',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ _responsavel: $('#txtResponsavel').val(), _ativo: $('#ckbAtivo').prop("checked"), _Un: checkedItemsUn,
            _motivo: checkedItemsMot, _pdv: checkedItemsPdv, _nivel: $('#cbxNivelResp').val()
        }),
        success: function (data) {

            str += '<div class="alert alert-success col-md-6">';
            str += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>';
            str += '<h4>Operação realizada com sucesso!</h4>';
            str += 'Registro gravado no banco de dados com sucesso.';
            str += '</div>';

            $('#alerta').html(str);

            str = "";
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Se fizeres `window.location.href = "/oTeuController/aTuaFuncao"` e carregares os dados no controller e enviar para a view deve resolver...

Comment: Devo colocar a minha função ou a Action? Coloquei a action e não funcionou. Qual função? Pois todas têm parâmeros e são para a funcionalidade da página, não entendi.

Comment: No fim de gravares os dados, no success fazes um `windows.location.href` para um função que irá carregar os dados para um view. Os parâmetros a pores é o teu controller primeiro e depois a tua função...

Comment: Fiz:  window.location.href = '/CadastroCargo/CadastroCargo'; Onde CadastroCargo é meu controller e minha Action e aí funcionou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se queres carregar novamente um view, podes usar o `window.location.href` no `success` do teu pedido Ajax.

Como tal, ficará algo do tipo:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/CadastroCargo/GravaResponsavel',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ _responsavel: $('#txtResponsavel').val(), _ativo: $('#ckbAtivo').prop("checked"), _Un: checkedItemsUn,
            _motivo: checkedItemsMot, _pdv: checkedItemsPdv, _nivel: $('#cbxNivelResp').val()
        }),
        success: function (data) {

            str += '<div class="alert alert-success col-md-6">';
            str += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>';
            str += '<h4>Operação realizada com sucesso!</h4>';
            str += 'Registro gravado no banco de dados com sucesso.';
            str += '</div>';

            $('#alerta').html(str);

            str = "";

            window.location.href = '/CadastroCargo/CadastroCargo' //AQUI
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
```

Onde na função `CadastroCargo` carregas os dados para carregar na view que pretendes.